# How do I make protected or package private fields public with asm?

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I am trying to write a classloader that can fix the access of a class' members, making protected and package private members public. The `loadClass` method that I have below checks if the class doesn't need modification and if it doesn't loads it normally. I am able to read the bytes of a class that needs modification, but I don't know what to do from there.

```java
@Override
public Class<?> loadClass(String className)
        throws ClassNotFoundException
{
    if (! this.needsAccessRepair(className))
        return super.loadClass(className);
    InputStream unmodified = this.getResourceAsStream(className.replace(".", "/") + ".class");
    // class that needs to be modified is modified
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Look at this library: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/

Comment: Try [the tutorial](https://asm.ow2.io/asm4-guide.pdf)

Comment: Asm, class visitor, replace/change the flags of the methods/fields to public (+ static/final... if they have that).